# jquery plugin methods -access indent methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have written a jquery plugin. I have defined methods like so:

```
(function($) {

    var methods = {
        init: function() {
            var initfunctions= {
                initbuttons: function() {
                    alert("bbb");
                }
                initnavbar: function() {
                    alert("ccc");
                }
            }
            subobject.initbuttons();
            subobject.initnavbar();
        },
        afterload: function() {
            ///some code 
            this.a.initfunctions.initbuttons(); //can't access b() from c function
        }
    };

    $.fn.dudaGallery = function() {


        return this.each(function() {
            methods.init();
            //methods.afterload();
        });

    };
})(jQuery);

$('#element').dudaGallery();   
​
```

I need to access b() function from c(), and I can't manage to do so. 
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ohadpartuck/uAzMJ/12/) is a jsfidde.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve there, but your problem is that the scope of `subobject` is limited to the `a()` function. Read more here about private members scope http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Comment: is there a way where I can globlize b()? or access it in another way?

Comment: Maybe if you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve. That would help to understand what approach is needed to structure the code. Your code is pretty abstract at this point

Answer (score 1):

Look's like you are not accessing it correctly here..

`subobject` has no scope in **c** , It is confined to **a**

`this.a.subobject.b();`  // Here **a** is a function

try this instead

```
 c: function() {
            ///some code 
            this.a();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I'm tring to access just b() function and not the entire a(). maybe it wasn't clear fro the question..I'll fix it